# injector error when trying to inject $scope into a service

Tags: angularjs, firebase

I'm trying to learn angular by extending a sample app to use firebase. I want to modify the service object being used to call firebase instead of my webserver. I tried to inject `$scope` into my service object and am now getting an error. What am I doing wrong?

```
    var app = angular.module("myApp", ['ngRoute', 'firebase']);

app.config(function($routeProvider) {
  $routeProvider.when('/', {
    templateUrl: "templates/home.html",
    controller: "HomeController"
  })
  .when('/settings', {
    templateUrl: 'templates/settings.html',
    controller: 'SettingsController'
  })
  .otherwise({ redirectTo: '/' });
});

//services must return objects
app.service('mailService', ['$scope', '$http', '$firebase', function($scope, $http, $firebase) {
  var mailRef = new Firebase("https://ng-book-email-client.firebaseio.com/mail");

  //var getMail = function() {
  //  return $http({
  //          method: 'GET',
  //          url: '/api/mail'
  //        });
  //};
  $scope.email = $firebase(mailRef);

  var sendEmail = function(mail) {
    //var d = $q.defer();
    //$http({
    //  method: 'POST',
    //  data: 'mail',
    //  url: '/api/send'
    //}).success(function(data, status, headers) {
    //  d.resolve(data);
    //}).error(function(data, status, headers) {
    //  d.reject(data);
    //});
    //return d.promise;
    return $scope.email.$add(mail);
  };

  return {
    //getMail: getMail,
    sendEmail: sendEmail
  };
}]);

app.controller('HomeController', function($scope) {
  $scope.selectedMail;

  $scope.setSelectedMail = function(mail) {
    $scope.selectedMail = mail;
  };

  $scope.isSelected = function(mail) {
    if($scope.selectedMail) {
      return $scope.selectedMail === mail;
    }
  };
});

// directive that builds the email listing
app.directive('emailListing', function() {
  var url = "http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/";
  return {
    restrict: 'EA', // E- element A- attribute C- class M- comment
    replace: false, // whether angular should replace the element or append
    scope: { // may be true/false or hash. if a hash we create an 'isolate' scope
      email: '=', // accept an object as parameter
      action: '&', // accept a function as a parameter
      isSelected: '&',
      shouldUseGravatar: '@', // accept a string as a parameter
      gravatarSize: '@'
    },
    transclude: false,
    templateUrl: '/templates/emailListing.html',
    controller: ['$scope', '$element', '$attrs', '$transclude',
      function($scope, $element, $attrs, $transclude) {
        $scope.handleClick = function() {
          $scope.action({selectedMail: $scope.email});
        };
      }
    ],
    // if you had a compile section here, link: wont run
    link: function(scope, iElement, iAttrs, controller) {
      var size = iAttrs.gravatarSize || 80;

      scope.$watch('gravatarImage', function() {
        var hash = md5(scope.email.from[0]);
        scope.gravatarImage = url + hash + '?s=' + size;
      });

      iElement.bind('click', function() {
        iElement.parent().children().removeClass('selected');
        iElement.addClass('selected');
      });
    }
  };
});

app.controller('MailListingController', ['$scope', 'mailService', function($scope, mailService) {
  $scope.email = [];
  $scope.nYearsAgo = 10;

  //mailService.getMail()
  //.success(function(data, status, headers) {
  //  $scope.email = data.all;
  //})
  //.error(function(data, status, headers) {
  //});

  $scope.searchPastNYears = function(email) {
    var emailSentAtDate = new Date(email.sent_at),
        nYearsAgoDate = new Date();

    nYearsAgoDate.setFullYear(nYearsAgoDate.getFullYear() - $scope.nYearsAgo);
    return emailSentAtDate > nYearsAgoDate;
  };
}]);

app.controller('ContentController', ['$scope', 'mailService', '$rootScope', function($scope, mailService, $rootScope) {
  $scope.showingReply = false;
  $scope.reply = {};

  $scope.toggleReplyForm = function() {
    $scope.reply = {}; //reset variable
    $scope.showingReply = !$scope.showingReply;
    console.log($scope.selectedMail.from);
    $scope.reply.to = $scope.selectedMail.from.join(", ");
    $scope.reply.body = "\n\n -----------------\n\n" + $scope.selectedMail.body;
  };

  $scope.sendReply = function() {
    $scope.showingReply = false;
    $rootScope.loading = true;
    mailService.sendEmail($scope.reply)
    .then(function(status) {
      $rootScope.loading = false;
    }, function(err) {
      $rootScope.loading = false;
    });
  }

  $scope.$watch('selectedMail', function(evt) {
    $scope.showingReply = false;
    $scope.reply = {};
  });
}]);

app.controller('SettingsController', function($scope) {
  $scope.settings = {
    name: 'harry',
    email: "me@me.com"
  };

  $scope.updateSettings = function() {
    console.log("updateSettings clicked")
  };
});
```

**error**

```
Error: [$injector:unpr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.14/$injector/unpr?p0=<div ng-view="" class="ng-scope">copeProvider%20%3C-%20%24scope%20%3C-%20mailService
at Error (native)
at https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.14/angular.min.js:6:450
at https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.14/angular.min.js:32:125
at Object.c [as get] (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.14/angular.min.js:30:200)
at https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.14/angular.min.js:32:193
at c (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.14/angular.min.js:30:200)
at d (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.14/angular.min.js:30:417)
at Object.instantiate (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.14/angular.min.js:31:80)
at Object.<anonymous> (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.14/angular.min.js:31:343)
at Object.d [as invoke] (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.14/angular.min.js:30:452) angular.js:9509
```

Comment: what is the actual error? is it in `app.service('mailService'` by any chance?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is that the $scope shouldn't be injected into services or factories. They're supposed to be reusable and sharable. The right way to achieve the effect is to create a `$firebase` object inside the service and return a function that can take any variable and scope and `$bind` them to the firebase object.

Inspiration comes from http://plnkr.co/edit/Uf2fB0?p=info

```
var app = angular.module("myApp", ['ngRoute', 'firebase']);    

//services must return objects
app.service('mailService', ['$http', '$firebase', function($http, $firebase) {
  var emailRef = new Firebase("https://ng-book-email-client.firebaseio.com/all");
  var emails = $firebase(emailRef);

  // uses firebase to bind $scope.email to the firebase mail object
  var setEmails = function(scope, localScopeVarName) {
    return emails.$bind(scope, localScopeVarName);
  };

  var sendEmail = function(mail) {
    return $scope.email.$add(mail);
  };

  return {
    setEmails: setEmails,
    sendEmail: sendEmail
  };
}]);

app.controller('MailListingController', ['$scope', 'mailService', function($scope, mailService) {
  mailService.setEmails($scope, 'emails');
  $scope.nYearsAgo = 10;

  $scope.searchPastNYears = function(email) {
    var emailSentAtDate = new Date(email.sent_at),
        nYearsAgoDate = new Date();

    nYearsAgoDate.setFullYear(nYearsAgoDate.getFullYear() - $scope.nYearsAgo);
    return emailSentAtDate > nYearsAgoDate;
  };
}]);
```

Comment: Please select this as the correct answer! Thanks Harry Moreno - it was a life saver.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should not inject `$scope` to a service, Service can be a common one for implementation /support for several controllers and service shouldn't know about a `$scope` (controller). But controllers users services to make their work done by passing parameters to a service method. 
    mailService.sendEmail($scope.reply)

Not sure why you need $scope inside a service here,

```
$scope.email = $firebase(mailRef);
```

are you expecting something like this,

```
this.email = $firebase(mailRef);
```

Comment: The original code was using the service to make an api call. I'm trying to adapt the code to work with a firebase in the simplest way and figured it'd be easier to do the db interactions in the service object. As opposed to modifying all the controllers to use the firebase.

Comment: Yeah that's true,  but why do you need the scope for that?

Comment: I'm not sure. I'm just following the example at https://www.firebase.com/quickstart/angularjs.html I see now that that's a controller in the example so I don't know how I _should_ be doing this. Angularfire provides 3-way databinding so it seems to make sense to attach `$scope.emails` to the firebase object.